# Get elements from other class using jQuery (Prettyphoto)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

I have a problem using jQuery and prettyPhoto (plugin for wordpress)! My problem is that i want to get image description from a hidden div, outside the already working a tag. This is what i have so far:

```
<div class="portfolie_short_content_containe">                  
    <a class="lightbox" style="text-decoration: none;" rel="lightbox" href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_desc; ?>">
        <span class="hover">
            <div class="portfolio_thump_hover_text">
                <span class="lable"><?php echo $short_descr;?></span><br>
                <span class="lable"><?php echo $link;?></span><br>
                <span class="lable"><FONT style="color : #f47b42;">Se CV</FONT></span>
            </div>
        </span>
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[1]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>"></img>
    </a>

    <!-- hidden div containing description -->
    <div id="lightbox" style="display: none"><p><?php echo $full_descr; ?></p><div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery.prettyphoto.js file looks like this!

```
theRel = $(this).attr('rel');
galleryRegExp = /\[(?:.*)\]/;
isSet = (galleryRegExp.exec(theRel)) ? true : false;
var x = 500;
var elmtid = $(this).attr('class');

// Put the SRCs, TITLEs, ALTs into an array.
pp_images = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i) {
    if ($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel) != -1) 
        return $(n).attr('href'); 
}) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('href'));

pp_titles = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i) { 
    if ($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel) != -1) 
        return ($(n).find('img').attr('alt')) ? $(n).find('img').attr('alt') : "";
}) : $.makeArray($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));

//Get text from hidden dir!     
pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i) {
    if ($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel) != -1) 
        return ($(n).find('p').text()) ? $(n).find('p').text() : ""; 
}) : $.makeArray($(this).find('p').text());
```

I'm not that experienced in jQuery. Can anyone help to get hold of the description? I have tried something like this!

```
pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i) {
    if($(n).attr('class') != -1) 
        return ($('#'+elmtid).html()) ? $('#'+elmtid).html()  : \"\"; 
}) : $.makeArray($('#'+elmtid).html());
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide some context for your code. For example, what is `this` in the first line of the js code referring to? You could create a working example in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: this refers to the jQuery object, not my code but part of the prettyphoto plugin, which creates a lightbox on homepage when a link is pressed, in this box i want some text loaded, but this text has links inside which messes up the <A href>

Comment: Oh, I see. What is the value for `elmtid` in the last snippet of code? What does the output HTML look like (without the PHP code, once it is rendered)? I think this will help understand the problem you are having.

Comment: Hmm tryid using a (debugger;) and the value of elmtid is "lightbox" if iam dont add the PHP text area is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, maybe easy but first time working jQuery!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

//reference the class instead of a tag
$j("div[class^='portfolie_short_content_containe']").prettyPhoto({theme: '<?php echo $portfolio_options["prtfl_prettyPhoto_style"]; ?>'});
});
</script>
```

IN the js file i changed this.

```
theRel = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
//theRel = $(this).attr('rel');
galleryRegExp = /\[(?:.*)\]/;
isSet = (galleryRegExp.exec(theRel)) ? true : false;
var x=500;

pp_images = $.makeArray($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
pp_titles = $.makeArray($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
pp_descriptions =  $.makeArray($(this).find('p').html());
```

It is not perfect but it works hope it helps other people with same issue.